# Scroll bar moves with client in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, scrollbar

I'm fairly new to MFC. I implemented a scroll bar to scroll the client area. When I scroll down the scroll bar also moves with the client. I want the scroll bar to stay where it is and just move the client.

I tried clipping the scroll bar and just moving the client but I can't get it to work. I used the ScrollWindow() to do so but I don't know how to clip the scroll bar. I don't know if I need the coordinates/dimensions of the scroll bar or what to get it to clip so for right now I have those parameters as NULL. I was focusing on just using the up and down buttons first to get the client to move correctly.

```
int UpPos;
    if ((pScrollBar == (CScrollBar *)&mMotorScrollBar)) {

        // Determine the new position of scroll box.
        int CurPos = mMotorScrollBar.GetScrollPos();

        switch (nSBCode)
        {
        case SB_TOP:      // Scroll to top.
            CurPos = 0;
            break;

        case SB_BOTTOM:    // Scroll to bottom.
            CurPos = 122;
            break;

        case SB_ENDSCROLL: // End scroll.
            break;

        case SB_LINEUP: // Scroll up when arrow up button is clicked.
            if (CurPos > 0)
                CurPos--;
                UpPos = -CurPos;
                ScrollWindow(0, UpPos, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case SB_LINEDOWN:   // Scroll down when arrow down button is clicked.
            if (CurPos < 122)
                CurPos++;
                ScrollWindow(0, CurPos, NULL, NULL);
            break;
```

[Application before I scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e6ru.png)

[Application after I scroll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0KIB.png)

[Window Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHIoH.png)

As you can see the scroll bar also moved with the client.

Comment: Probably because the handling for the event WM_VSCROLL is missing.
This [link](https://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/scrollbar.htm)
will give some clues.

Comment: It's not missing I have that added in the message mapping otherwise my vertical scroll bar wouldn't be working at all. It works it just scrolls the client along with the scroll bar.

Comment: How did you create the scollbar? Did you drag & drop a scrollbar control in to dialog editor? In that case, the above code will move the whole window with the scrollbar in it. Instead you want to make the window have vertical/horizontal scrollbar property. Or use `CView` if it's not a dialog. Show more information about your window and how the scroller is created, and what you want it to do...

Comment: I created the scroll bar by dragging in a scroll bar from the toolbox into the dialog editor. I saw the vertical scroll bar option in window properties but I didn't know where to add functionality to it. So instead I made CScrollBar. gave it an ID, etc like all the other buttons and sliders.

Comment: Maybe consider a totally different implementation? For example, a window with built-in standard scroll-bars? Check the Windows documentation for the `WS_HSCROLL` and `WS_VSCROLL` window styles. These scroll-bars are automatically displayed, and are not like scroll-bar controls placed on a dialog's client area. MFC's `CScrollView` and `CFormView` classes display scroll-bars themselves if needed, and you need do nothing but define the scrollable area's size, everything else is already contained in the MFC library implementation.

Comment: It's rather normal that the scroll bar moves with the client, because that scroll bar is just another control amoung edit controls, static controls etc. There is no reason why it should not move. The approach mentioned by Constantine Georgiou looks good. Another possibility is not scrolling the window content but move the invididual controls (except the scrollbar of course) yourself by calling `MoveWindow` for each of them, but with this solution you might get ugly flicker.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the scrollbar control and add vertical scroller using `SetScrollInfo`. `SetScrollInfo` has to be called when window is created, it will add a scroll bar and it adjusts the client area.

Additionally, you can edit dialog box and set the vertical scroll option. This option doesn't actually do anything except it adjusts the position of dialog controls in dialog editor. The actual scroll bar has to be created using `SetScrollInfo` during run time. Example:

```
BOOL CMyPropertyPage::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();
    SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    si.nMax = 122; //<- this should be calculated dynamically for DPI compatibility
    si.nPage = 1;
    SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
    return res;
}

void CMyPropertyPage::OnVScroll(UINT sbCode, UINT, CScrollBar*)
{
    SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, SIF_ALL);
    int save = si.nPos;
    switch(sbCode)
    {
    case SB_LINEDOWN:      si.nPos += 1; break;
    case SB_LINEUP:        si.nPos -= 1; break;
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:      si.nPos += si.nPage; break;
    case SB_PAGEUP:        si.nPos -= si.nPage; break;
    case SB_TOP:           si.nPos = 0; break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:        si.nPos = si.nMax; break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:    si.nPos = si.nTrackPos; break;
    default:break;
    }
    if(si.nPos < 0) si.nPos = 0;
    if(si.nPos > si.nMax) si.nPos = si.nMax;
    SetScrollPos(SB_VERT, si.nPos); //update scrollbar position
    ScrollWindow(0, save - si.nPos); //scroll the window
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading: [There are two types of scrollbars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).